# gdb doesn't recognize `typedef` or `using` in c++ binary compiled `-g3`

Tags: c++, gdb

In my C++ program (compiled with `-g3`) there are many `typedef` and `using` statements such as:

```
using TreeVertex = <really long fully-qualified name>;
```

Sometimes in GDB I need to specify the type name, for example to compare a field of `enum class` type with one of the enum constants. But GDB does not recognize `TreeVertex` as a symbol. Is there any way to enable this? Or can I at least define an alias within GDB so that I can just refer to `TreeVertex::Mode` instead of `<really long fully-qualified name>::Mode`?

Comment: `using` just provides a compile time alias for the type, it doesn’t define a type that would be in the result. That’s why gen doesn’t know anything about the alias. Don’t know if there’s a way to define type aliases in gdb, at least can’t find any direct way

Answer (score 0):

`using` != `typedef`

It appears that `g++` will only emit debug info for `typedef` or `using` under certain circumstances.

```
// t0.cc
namespace foo::bar::baz {
struct Zork {
  enum E { AA, BB, CC };
};
}

using EE = ::foo::bar::baz::Zork::E;
typedef ::foo::bar::baz::Zork::E TE;

int main()
{
  auto a = EE::AA;
  auto b = TE::BB;
  return a == b;
}

$ g++ -g -c t0.cc && readelf -wi t0.o | egrep ' (EE|TE)'
# no output
```

As you can see, there is no trace of the `using` or `typedef` anywhere in the debug info, so GDB has no chance.

Now let's change the source by introducing a function taking `EE` and `TE`:

```
// t1.cc
namespace foo::bar::baz {
struct Zork {
  enum E { AA, BB, CC };
};
}

using EE = ::foo::bar::baz::Zork::E;
typedef ::foo::bar::baz::Zork::E TE;

int fn1(EE x) { return x; }
int fn2(TE x) { return x; }

int main()
{
  auto a = EE::AA;
  auto b = TE::BB;
  return fn1(a) == fn2(b);
}

$ g++ -g -c t1.cc && readelf -wi t1.o | egrep ' (EE|TE)'
    <7a>   DW_AT_name        : EE
    <85>   DW_AT_name        : TE
```

That looks promising! Compiling the entire program gives:

```
g++ -g  t1.cc && gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...

(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x1146: file t1.cc, line 15.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at t1.cc:15
15        auto a = EE::AA;
(gdb) p (EE)1
$1 = foo::bar::baz::Zork::BB
(gdb) p (TE)2
$2 = foo::bar::baz::Zork::CC
```

Versions used:

```
gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6+build2) 10.2.1 20210110
GNU gdb (GDB) 11.0.50.20210131-git  # 10.0 also works the same way.
```